# In KOTLIN, if the Array can get user input?

Tags: kotlin

my solution:
(I was try to find some more i didn't get solution can you help
)

```
val n1=Scanner(System.`in`)
println("Enter an number of input: ")
val n:Int=n1.nextInt()
val n3:ArrayList<Int> =ArrayList()
var i=0
for (i in 1..n){

    print("enter an input of $i :")
    val v=n1.nextInt()

    n3.add(v)
}
println("the list is:$n3")
```

Comment: What is your question? This is a code block with no context. I don't know what you expect an answer to this question to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had better to use the standard kotlin function *readln()* over Java class *Scanner* because that way you're gonna less code using that, and code more *Kotlin idiomatic* (readln() is a function which makes part of the *Kotlin Standard Library*, reason by which makes more sense to use it because one's a native feature of the Kotlin language).

I refactored your code, and renamed some variables hoping to ease your understand about my code.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println("Enter a number of input: ")
    val inputAmount: Int = readln().toInt()
    val arrayList: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
    var i = 0
    for (i in 1..inputAmount){

        print("Enter an input of the position $i: ")
        val input: Int = readln().toInt()
        arrayList.add(input)
    }
    println("the list is: $arrayList")
}
```

References:

- [readln](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/readln.html)